# C# Design Time Path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm using a number of C# custom controls (forms, buttons, etc) which use a skinning system, and are dependent on external images (in a zip file) within the project folder. Right now, the form designer is unable to show the controls, because I can't get the correct path to the zip file. What I need is a way to get the path to the assembly or solution at design time.

I am using two projects:

DLL - Contains the custom controls.

Host application - References the DLL and uses the custom controls.

In my DLL custom control classes, at runtime, I'm simply using:

```
string skinPath = "./Skins/" + skin + ".zip";
```

which works perfectly, but at design time, the form designer displays the error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Skins\Black.zip'.
```

Having looked at similiar questions on the site, I've tried the following too:
1)

```
if (designMode)
{
    EnvDTE.DTE dte = GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);
}
```

The form designer displays the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

2)

```
if (designMode)
{
    ITypeResolutionService typeResService = GetService(typeof(ITypeResolutionService)) as ITypeResolutionService;
    string path = typeResService.GetPathOfAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName());
}
```

The form designer displays the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

3) A variety of different paths using the Assembly class.

Nothing as of yet has worked.
I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express.

Comment: Ugh. Don't use `as` like that. Use a cast instead.

Comment: Sorry, but it wasn't my code. I've been copying and pasting code from lots of different questions, trying different solutions.

Comment: Then copy `Black.zip` to `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/Skins/` :)

Comment: Not really very convenient is it :P

Comment: Yes but it is a quick solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd attempt (`ITypeResolutionService`) should work fine. Just make sure you call `GetService` late enough, so `Site` property would be non-null. `OnHandleCreated` is fine, control constructor is way too soon and produces `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: This solved it. Thank you very much. While the code in option 2 didn't work, you were right about calling it too early. I added the code from option 1 in the OnLoad event handler, and bingo :D Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Further update, with a bit of adjustment to the path, option 2 worked as well :)